# Image Compression Approaches for CNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-processing, compression

I have a set of images, which are quite large in size and as such do not easily fit into memory for feeding a CNN. (1000x1000). I'd like to compress and encode these images, such that little information is lost. What is the best approach to handle this issue for CNNs without resorting to downscaling the image and losing a great deal of information?

Answer (score 1):

You may use [image downsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling) to preprocess images before feeding to neural network. (For example AlexNet takes 256*256 RGB as input.)

[image]

Note the word "compression" is confusing, because I assume the goal is using neural network to do some classification but not trying to reduce size, and recover later.

Comment: Yes, but downsampling, I think, removes needed information from the image. I'm looking for a method of encoding the image, such that most of the information is still in the encoding, but the encoding is much more compact than the image.

Comment: @ZeroMaxinumXZ why it "removes needed information"? which information is needed? We still see it is a TV after downsampling right?

Comment: Fair point. However, I am looking to use the CNN for a reinforcement learning task that happens to have quite small objects that I'm afraid will have an impact on performance once the image is downsampled.